# Font issue crossbrowser IE8

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, webfonts

I've some web font issues.

Font is loaded in a standard css minified. There is another font loaded that does work.

```
@font-face{font-family:'RobotoSlab-Regular';src:url('https://static1.chitzi.com/font/58c8b855e7d91c77261dca2b8a3c4203/1ec06eed11bbcb1ee510b8f3522adea8.eot');src:url('https://static1.chitzi.com/font/58c8b855e7d91c77261dca2b8a3c4203/1ec06eed11bbcb1ee510b8f3522adea8.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('https://static1.chitzi.com/font/28df5a322ea4027f2045e9151170024e/1ec06eed11bbcb1ee510b8f3522adea8.woff') format('woff'),url('https://static1.chitzi.com/font/8da46efd59a7d2e66f08b789da7a993f/1ec06eed11bbcb1ee510b8f3522adea8.ttf') format('truetype'),url('https://static1.chitzi.com/font/18e6bde1da5c81cbd91346b37a5ac7dc/1ec06eed11bbcb1ee510b8f3522adea8.svg#webfont') format('svg')}
```

I've tried those:

- Substitute ' with " or remove it
- Use no ssl url
- Create a single "font css file"
- Use no minified css

Nothing worked.

Comment: Instead of trying random things have you opened your console to debug the problem?

Comment: No information in IE8

Comment: Some information: Microsoft has discontinued IE8 on all platforms. It was officially killed off on January 12th of this year. Finally. The only IE versions that Microsoft now support are IE11/EDGE on Windows 7 and above, and IE9 on Windows Vista SP2 (and *only* SP2). Any older version of Windows is already out of support, and whatever browsers they support should probably not matter because the OS it runs on is about as secure as a house with all the doors open and big signs saying "please steal everything you can find". That said, IE8 can *only* do `eot` webfonts.

Comment: Yes, I know but please it tell to the people that still uses that stupid program.